# Child nodes not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, row, children

i have a problem, my code works 100% fine on Chrome and what it does is it gets the text and value from in table rows but as soon as it goes to IE it stops working and i have narrowed it down to childNodes here is a quick sample of the code that doesn't work in IE:

```
var t = document.getElementById('tableFull');

for (var i = 1, row; row = t.rows[i]; i++) {

   var tee = t.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].rowIndex;
   var subtractCost =t.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
   var subtractName = t.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;

}
```

Anyone know how i can replace the childNodes here for IE?

Answer (score 1):

The counting of childNodes varies. Some browsers include empty textNodes, some do not. In this sort of operation as I believe you are describing, it is better to use the parent's `getElementsByTagName()` method. That way the number of chidren and index of each child you are looking for will be consistent.

Or You Can try `.children` instead of `childNodes`

Hope this will help